# Blank Sharepoint Administration Page after install

Tags: 2013, central-administration, installation

I have installed SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (just as a practice). However, I am getting a blank Central Administration page.

So far, I have:

1. Did a clean install three times
2. Configured authentication settings as shown in the following image[image: Auth]

I am getting this from the page source

```
        <html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX " /></head><body></body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
             var gearPage = document.getElementById('GearPage');
             if(null != gearPage)
             {
                 gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
                 document.title = "Error";
             }
             </script>
         </html>
```

I have no idea how to add the Central Admin app pool user account to Local  admins group.

The Admin account I use is the same for both local computer and as well as domain admin, `username: Administrator`
[image]

5. Disabled the loopback-check

Comment: Any help is appreciated